# SVG pause/play Can not figure out why this isn't working...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I need code to work just like on [this page](http://www.svgopen.org/2008/presentations/70-Tricks_of_Javascript_and_declarative_animation/anim.svg).

Play and pausing of an SVG.  I went into inspect and pulled all the code I could, which seemed to be HTML.  I could not see or find CSS or Javascript.  Not sure if that is normal.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="80 0 1024 768" onload="t=setInterval(updateTimer, 100)">
  
<script>
  var time = 0;
  function updateTimer() {
    //document.getElementById("t").textContent = document.documentElement.getCurrentTime().toFixed(0) + "s";
  }
  function pause() {
    time = document.documentElement.getCurrentTime();
    document.documentElement.pauseAnimations();
    clearInterval(t);
  }
  function play() {
    if(time &gt; 0)
      document.documentElement.setCurrentTime(time);

    clearInterval(t);
    t=setInterval(updateTimer, 100);    
    document.documentElement.unpauseAnimations();
  }
  function stop() {
    time = 0;
    clearInterval(t);
    document.documentElement.setCurrentTime(0); 
    document.documentElement.pauseAnimations();
  }
  </script>
  
<linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,80%,10%)" offset="0"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,40%,20%)" offset="0.4"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,90%,30%)" offset="0.7"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,50%,40%)" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  
<rect fill="url(#grad)" width="0%" height="50" x="100" y="300" rx="5">
    <animate attributeName="width" to="100%" begin="0s" dur="30s"/>
  </rect>
  
<text id="t" style="font:24px Arial Black;fill:white;stroke:black" transform="translate(100 334)"/>
  
<animateTransform type="translate" attributeName="transform" xlink:href="#t" begin="1s" dur="29s" from="100 334" to="1024 334"/>
  
<g transform="translate(100 500)">
    
<!-- Play -->
   <g onclick="play()">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
     <path id="play" d="M12 5l20 15l-20 15Z" fill="white" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
   
<!-- Pause -->
   <g transform="translate(50 0)">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5" onclick="pause();"/>
     <path id="pause" d="M14 10l0 20M26 10l0 20" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
   
<!-- Stop (rewind and pause) -->
   <g transform="translate(100 0)">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5" onclick="stop()"/>
     <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="white" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I attempt playback on Code pen, the SVG plays but buttons don't work. At all.  I thought the "onclick" would do it...?

Is this because the JS isn't accessible/applied?  I don't see any "DIV" or "DOM" so I assume its not a CSS thing...

I have a basic knowledge of HTML, less of CSS and know NOTHING about JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short version:** getCurrentTime & setCurrentTime must be called on the SVG node.

```js
const mySvg = document.getElementById("mySvg")

function updateTimer() {
  const t = `${mySvg.getCurrentTime().toFixed(0)}s`;
  document.getElementById("t").textContent = t;
}

function setCurrentTime(t) {
  mySvg.setCurrentTime(t)
}

function pause() {
  mySvg.pauseAnimations()
}

function play() {
  mySvg.unpauseAnimations()
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval();
  setCurrentTime(0);
  mySvg.pauseAnimations()
  updateTimer();
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="80 0 1024 768" onload="t=setInterval(updateTimer, 100)">
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,80%,10%)" offset="0"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,40%,20%)" offset="0.4"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,90%,30%)" offset="0.7"/>
    <stop stop-color="rgb(10%,50%,40%)" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect fill="url(#grad)" width="0%" height="50" x="100" y="300" rx="5">
    <animate attributeName="width" to="100%" begin="0s" dur="30s"/>
  </rect>
  <text id="t" style="font:24px Arial Black;fill:white;stroke:black" transform="translate(100 334)"/>
  <animateTransform type="translate" attributeName="transform" xlink:href="#t" begin="1s" dur="29s" from="100 334" to="1024 334"/>
  <g transform="translate(100 500)">
    <!-- Play -->
    <g onclick="play()">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
     <path id="play" d="M12 5l20 15l-20 15Z" fill="white" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
   <!-- Pause -->
   <g transform="translate(50 0)">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5" onclick="pause();"/>
     <path id="pause" d="M14 10l0 20M26 10l0 20" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="8" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
   <!-- Stop (rewind and pause) -->
   <g transform="translate(100 0)">
     <rect width="40" height="40" rx="10" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.5" onclick="stop()"/>
     <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="white" pointer-events="none"/>
   </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

**Long version:** After all that, why wasn't it working in Codepen?
I can see that the link you posted is to an [SVG document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) with it's own inline JavaScript (in the script tag).

The script calls some [SVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) methods on the SVG root element with `document.documentElement.pauseAnimations();`.
But what exactly is [document element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)?

> Document.documentElement returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the  element for HTML documents).

Because this code was called inside an SVG document, `document.documentElement` returns the SVG root node. However, because codepen is an HTML document, `document.documentElement` will return the HTML root node.

And you can't call methods like `pauseAnimations()` on an HTML root node because the HTML root node doesn't understand those methods.

So modern browsers can display SVG documents, HTML documents (and more) but here's the kicker: SVG documents can live *inside* of HTML documents.

You can see how `document.documentElement` could refer to two potential things depending on what type of document the JavaScript code was run from.

Comment: Good news! I figured out that the top code you posted was the JS I was missing... Bad news; I feel like a dumbass for not getting that it wasn't just part of the script, like I first thought! Thanks! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!